# Jade closes a SVG attribute which shouldn't be closed

Tags: svg, attributes, pug

I am using the [`<feTurbulence>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feTurbulence#Example) attribute for a svg animation and currently use Jade as my HTML engine.

---

**Jade**:

```
  feTurbulenc (
    baseFrequency="1 1.25"
    numOctaves="1"
  )
```

**HTML**:

```
<feTurbulence baseFrequency="1 1.25" numOctaves="1"></feTurbulence> <--- BAD

<feTurbulence baseFrequency="1 1.25" numOctaves="1" /> <--- GOOD
```

---

It seems that jade puts an ending tag to the attribute which it shouldn't, according to w3

**[Article](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feTurbulenceElement)**

**[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWNjbE)**

Is there anyway I could fix this?

Comment: Aren't the two equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Ending tags are definitely allowed.  Not least because there are elements that can be placed inside filter primitives (like `<feTurbulence>`). `<animate>` is one example.

> it shouldn't, according to w3

Where are you getting that information?